# Force a C# program which uses HttpClient to use IPv6 only when also IPv4 is available

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming, ipv6

I have a C# program, which also depends on other libraries, which uses HttpClient through the libraries to get data from a server.

On the machine where I run the program, I have both IPv6 and IPv4 available.

I want to make sure that the program uses IPv6 only for its HttpClient connections, excluding IPv4.

Is there a way to achieve this, possibly without having to modify the source code of the libraries which use HttpClient, i.e. with some kind of "per process" setting in the Main method which disables IPv4 for the whole process?

Comment: Temporarily deactivating IPv4 on your network adapter isn't an option, I assume. Right?

Comment: @sbecker unfortunately deactivating IPv4 on the network adapter is not an option. Or better: it's the very last option if nothing else can be done, because other services depend on IPv4 and would need to be moved to a different machine with quite some additional work

Comment: Out of interest, why do you want to force IPv6 (I'm just wondering if you can achieve your outcome with some other mechanism)? One option would be to use the IPv6 address in lieu of the hostname in the URL - if your webserver needs the hostname, then use a proxy like Fiddler or nginx running on an IPv6 address to redirect the traffic to the correct server.

Comment: @RB Thanks for your options. Using the IPv6 address would require to modify the libraries on which the program depends, I would have liked to avoid it, but can be done. Now that you make me think about it, I could also resolve the IPv6 address of the webserver then force it in hosts file. In this way the server would still receive the correct hostname without having to modify the libraries. I hoped there was an easier solution, but can be done.

Comment: @EnricoDetoma With respect, you haven't explained *why* you have to use the IPv6 address - is there something funky about your networking that requires it? Are you trying to prove that your application will work in an IPv6 environment? What is your purpose?

Comment: @RB I need to increase the number of the http connections beyond the number of available ports. With IPv6 I have more available source IPs than IPv4 on that network, so more available ports.

Comment: You need more than 65 thousand concurrent outbound HTTP connections from a single machine??! With respect, you're gonna need to explain that one as well! It's worth noting that, by default, `HttpClient` [will be limited](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/managing-connections) to (it depends but typically) 6 connections to any given host-name - not six thousand, or sixty thousand, but _six_. Are you trying to load-test the web-server by any chance?

Comment: @RB I'm trying to make a large scale financial data crawler, so it's not one webserver only, but I understand your point: using HttpClient is NOT the right tool for the job.

Comment: @EnricoDetoma Ah, interesting use-case! One option would be to write your own HTTP client with TcpClient. That way you have complete control over the IP address etc. and if you are basically just doing GET requests with some basic headers, it's probably not *that* much work... Just throwing it out there as an option :)

Comment: @EnricoDetoma Are you completely sure the machine where you're running this from even supports 65 thousand active connections? That's quite a huge number of threads working in parallel.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto It's a Linux machine running .NET Core 3.1 (just because I already had quite a number of financial data libraries in .NET and didn't want to rewrite the code or search for other libraries in other languages). Using IPv6 seemed to give me better options for the crawler, but I'm not yet to the point of that level of stress on that machine, and I could well decide to increase the number of machines.

Comment: You might be better off creating a very small piece of code to retrieve the data from a given URL and then use something like Hangfire or an HPC scheduler to actually execute everything

Answer (score 0):

Check this: [Disable/Enable IPv6](https://eniackb.blogspot.com/2009/07/how-to-disable-ipv6-in-windows-2008.html)

You can basically modify the registry. It is a bit of a hack fix, but I can't think of another solution at the moment.

Comment: Not Windows unfortunately, but Linux with .NET Core 3.1 and I can't completely disable IPv4 for the whole machine for now.